# Disable directory browsing for particular folders

Tags: .htaccess

I used the below to disable ,but my subdomains also not accessing .is there any code for only keeping for some folders ?

```
# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable directory browsing using htaccess and mod_rewrite, and you'd be able to do it only under certain conditions. For example,in an htaccess file in the directory you want to disable directory browsing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !subdomain.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ - [L,F]
```

This will disable directory listing only if the host isn't `subdomain.domain.com`.

Or:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !123.45.67.89 [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ - [L,F]
```

This will disable directory listing only if the request isn't made from the IP: 123.45.67.89

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you put the code in a .htaccess file in your web root folder. You can instead use the same code in a .htaccess file in each of the folders you want to prevent directory browsing.